# How to use \qed in a mathematical equation in LaTeX?

Tags: equations, amsmath, theorems, amsthm, proof-package

I like to place a \blacksquare or a \Box at the end of a worked example. This does not pose any problem in a text sentence in LaTeX. But when I type \qed in a mathematical equation at the end, LaTeX gives me compiling error. Kindly help me on it - Thanks a lot!

Sample code:

```
\begin{equation}
 A = B + C \qed
 \end{equation}
```

Error message:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.859  A = B + C \qed
                     
?
```

Comment: Please extend your sniplet to a full minimal including document class and relevant preamble. Then we have a better idea of that exactly we are dealing with

Comment: Please do as @daleif suggests. `\qed` is not defined without packages, and we don't know what packages you have loaded. If you only load `amsthm`, your code above works fine.

Comment: @frabjous -- `\qedhere` only works if the equation is at the end of a theorem.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I know, but why are you mentioning that here? My point was that the original code with `\qed` (not `\qedhere`) works fine with just `amsthm` loaded.

Comment: @frabjous -- With just `amsthm` loaded, the `\qed` will be set right at the end of the equation.  But I think the OP is expecting it to be flush right, and that won't happen unless the equation is in a proof.  The OP needs to be more clear about what is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use \qedhere at the end of an equation.

Comment: I ran the same LaTeX file with \qedhere instead of \qed. It compiled successfully but I am not seeing any symbol at the right end of the (math) equation. How to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: I think `\qedhere` only works inside a proof environment.

Comment: @Jay -- This only works if the equation is at the end of a proof.